# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in class instance using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I making project in Kotlin with MVP design pattern first time. Why I have got `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

This is my error from debuger:  https://pastebin.com/U1nwjaf6

This is my class `DbManager`: https://pastebin.com/KRpa2eRF

And this is my class `LoginPresenter`: https://pastebin.com/Vryf0kBH

I am beginner on making apps using Kotlin.
Please help me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post the necessary code and logs as text. Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

**Some tips:**
You should post everything related to your code. It makes easier for people to help you and give better answers. You should also paste code in the question itself instead of giving links to pastebin. Only use pastebin like services when your code is too big. Which is not the case here (but you did right with the error message, it is big).

Now, to the problem itself.

You seem to be instantianting the class `DbManager`, according to the error messages. This class instantiates your other class, `LoginPresenter` here:

```
class DbManager
{
   ...     
   val loginPresenter: LoginPresenter = LoginPresenter()
   ...
}
```

`LoginPresenter` will instantiate the class `DbManager`:

```
class LoginPresenter
{
    ...
    val dbManager: DbManager = DbManager()
    ...
}
```

`DbManager` creates `LoginPresenter` which creates `DbManager` which creates `LoginPresenter` which creates...

See the pattern here? It creates a infinite loop, with recursion, that will create classes until you run out of memory. Hence, the error.

It is hard to tell you what you should do when I only have this part of the code. But, *I think* that you should instantiate the `DbManager` class only once, globally and use that instance everytime you want to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because of StackOverflow :)

DBManager & LoginPresenter instances are getting created in a loop and causing this, you should move instance creation into some method